# Checking out from master and used -f with uncommitted changes

Tags: git, gitignore, git-commit, git-checkout

I am working for a company and we have a download counter on our website that is updated daily, so every time I pull from the remote repository there are changes that need to be committed, but I've been told to ignore this and that the Lead Developer will shove into a .gitignore folder at some point in the future (counter is a new addition to the website).

The problem is this:

I went to go checkout of the master branch and it wouldn't let me because I have uncommitted changes; being fairly new to git I used:

```
git checkout content-fs-04112021 -f
```

(I'm gonna assume that '-f' means force)

Now when I checkout of the master branch again and use:

```
git status
```

It says my branch is up to date with origin/master and that there isn't anything to commit.

My intention wasn't to commit anything, but I just want to know what happened to my modified files.

Did I commit the changes on the master branch? If not, why don't the modified files show up?

Comment: You didn't commit your changes to master, it's likely that you have lost your local changes to those files because the `-f` forces the checkout and replaces the contents of those files. In future using `git stash` first is probably what you want to do (stash your local changes to have a clean working copy and can then check out a different commit without needing `-f`)

Comment: Or, to put it another way: `-f` *does* mean "force", which in turn means "yes I know I'm going to lose my work forever, I intend to do that". You'll have to recover the work some other way (from backups, or by re-doing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use force checkout to another branch using:

```
git checkout branch_name -f
```

then you throw away your local changes and any untracked files.

Basically in your scenario, you discarded your local changes and did not commit and push anything to master branch.

Answer (score 0):

That is why using [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of the obsolete git checkout command is better.

It will abort if the operation leads to loss of local changes.
And the way to force the switch is to add `--discard-changes` (which is more explicit than `-f`: your changes will be lost) or `--merge`.

In your case, you would need to check with your IDE to recreate lost changes:

For instance, VSCode, has a timeline view which provides a local history of said file, allowing you to restore a past content (even when not saved in a Git commit)
That supposes however that you remember which files were modified.

The other option is to check if you had [activated Time Machine on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250).